# Why doesn't @State wrapped variable update immediately in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

According to the documentation, modifying a `@State` wrapped variable will refresh the view which refers that variable. But when I was trying to change the `@State` wrapped variable `counter` in a loop, I found it only changed when the loop had finished. I also wrote some code with `DispatchQueue`. The code using `DispatchQueue` can update the `counter` immediately (i.e. I can see the continuously changing value in `Text`).

So I am wondering why these two pieces of code perform differently.

Here is my code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var counter: Int = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Counter value: \(counter)")
                .padding()
            Button("Begin Counting (Sync)", action: {() -> Void in
                for _ in 0..<100000 {
                    counter += 1
                }
            })
            Button("Begin Counting (Async)", action: {() -> Void in
                DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async {
                    for _ in 0..<100000 {
                        counter += 1
                    }
                }
            })
        }.frame(width: 200, height: 200, alignment: .center)
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you must update the UI only on the main queue. This includes updating @State variables. This will work:

```
            DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async {
                for _ in 0..<100000 {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async { counter += 1 }
                }
            }
```

Answer (score -1):

If the goal is to increase counter +1 up to 1000 remove the for statement and edit the counter action:

`counter += counter < 1000 ? 1 : 0`